# target = []: ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 156

Tags: python, linux, error-handling

Thats the code where the mistake is

```
if tool == ("11"):
target = []:

with open('freesec.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        url = str(line.replace('\n',''))
        targets.append(url)

for url in targets:
    if 'http://' in url:
        url = url.replace('http://', '')
    elif 'https://' in url:
        url = url.replace('https://', '')
    url = 'http://' + url

    response = requests.get(url + "'").text
    if 'error' in response and 'syntax' in response or 'MySQL' in response:
        print 'Gotcha!!! ' + url
    else:
        print 'No luck here :( ' + url
```

Thats the image of my terminal when i was fixing the tool

Comment: Why do you have a `:` at the end of your first line?

Comment: I thought it would solve it

Comment: which line is line 156? Also seems you are trying to use a list called `targets` but have created a list called `target` - one has an s at the end.

Comment: the first line ```if tool == ("11"):```

Comment: okay well there's your indentation error (with the new line you just added it is clear now). So ... fix the indentation problem.

Comment: I didnt add any new line

Comment: Yes - you did. It is in the edit history of your question. You edited the question :)

Comment: Yeah i was just showing line 156 because it wasnt visible

Comment: So i removed the : from line 156 and i got this ```File "/home/bx7/wtf.py", line 156
    if tool == ("11")
                     ^
SyntaxError: expected ':'
```

Comment: The suggestion was to remove the colon after `target = []:` Also you have an indentation problem on that line. It is not possible to provide an (obvious) correction because it is not clear what you want your if statement to do .... what is supposed to happen `if tool == ("11")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to find solutions to common problems yourself first before asking. For example, try [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+what+is+indentationerror) to look up error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the error. You are missing the indentation.

```py
# incorrect
if tool == ("11"):
target = []:

# correct
if tool == ("11"):
    target = []:
```

Reason:
Python reqires indentation to recognise blocks of code.